# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page error occur in magento 2

Tags: magento2.3, payment-methods, form-key

if i try to pay with paytm am getting this error "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page error" How do i fix it

Answer (score 0):

You can try by increasing the value of `max_input_vars` in `php.ini` file. By default, this value is set to `1000`. You should set it to `5000` or `10000`.

Then Restart your server and check that process.

Comment: I have tried this but this is not working for me . I used a custom payment method (paytm) and it's redirects to home page with the same message

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below query

```
DELETE FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';
```

Then run the below commands via CLI:

```
sudo php bin/magento cache:flush

sudo php bin/magento cache:clean
```